# Prevent Child PageViewController to swipe Parent PageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

[image]As you can see product images are in child `pageVC` and the whole content is in parent Page `vc`

[image]

The problem is after scrolling to last image instead of bounce it swipe to another vc of `ParentPageVC`
I tried adding pan gesture to child `pageVC` but the problem is the `childPageVC` is not bouncing any more

Comment: Could you share your  code what you did ? And image not clear what trying to do

Comment: as you see in flip cart app there are multiple products and you can swipe through them okay.there may be multiple images of one single product and you can swipe through those images too.. same is happening in my case too but when I swipe to last image of particular image it scrolls the complete parent page vc too